# JSTL on AppEngine - tags not working

Tags: google-app-engine, jstl

I want to use JSTL in my AppEngine JSP to render data. I have completed the [Guestbook demo](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore), which works fine for me, including the JSTL calls like this one (from the linked example):

```
<blockquote>${fn:escapeXml(greeting_content)}</blockquote>
```

However, I then tried to use JSTL through tags, e.g. this:

```
<fn:out value="greeting_content" />
```

or just

```
<fn:out value="" />
```

I get a 500 error and an exception stack trace saying:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /guestbook.jsp(80,4) No tag "out" defined in tag library imported with prefix "fn"
```

The JSTL library is imported at the top of the file as in the example, i.e.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

And as expected, if I remove that line the ${fn:something} calls stop working.

Does anyone have an idea why that is? JSTL is supposed to work that way, isn't it? I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here, but I just can't find what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<c:out value=""/>` for output.

Comment: With <c:out>, I don't get an exception but it simply isn't compiled. It just shows up as a tag in the resulting raw HTML. Note that the Guestbook example imports JSTL with the prefix fn: rather than c: as shown above.

Comment: Add this declaration: `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`. FN does not contain method "out".

Comment: That is indeed working! The part that I missed was that it's importing jsp/jstl/functions, but not jsp/jstl/core. Thanks a lot!